# JSON API returns multiple arrays, need help flattening the data to store in SQL Server database table

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server

I am stuck on a problem on trying to flatten a JSON API response to store in a SQL Server table.

The API returns the following:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "header": [
        {
            "type": "date.day",
            "rows": [
                "2023-01-01",
                "2023-01-02",
                "2023-01-03"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "profile",
            "rows": [
                "11111111111",
                "22222222222"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "metric",
            "rows": [
                "post_clicks",
                "adds_unique",
                "engaged_users"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "data": [
        [
            [
                73,
                0,
                50
            ],
            [
                41,
                6,
                48
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                61,
                3,
                38
            ],
            [
                22,
                5,
                46
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                59,
                1,
                41
            ],
            [
                74,
                1,
                60
            ]
        ]
    ] }
```

In the header array

- the first object is always the date dimension. In the example, I am querying 3 days, but it could be more or less
- the second object is always the profile dimension. The lists all the profiles that I pass into it
- the third object is always the metric fields. These are the specified fields that I want to see the data for for the above dimensions.

In the data array, is the actual values for the metrics specified based on the dimensions.

What I'm trying to do is get the desired output like this in SQL Server table like so:

| date | profile | metric | metric_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 11111111111 | post_clicks | 73 |
| 2023-01-01 | 11111111111 | adds_unique | 0 |
| 2023-01-01 | 11111111111 | engaged_users | 50 |
| 2023-01-01 | 22222222222 | post_clicks | 41 |
| 2023-01-01 | 22222222222 | adds_unique | 6 |
| 2023-01-01 | 22222222222 | engaged_users | 48 |
| 2023-01-02 | 11111111111 | post_clicks | 61 |
| 2023-01-02 | 11111111111 | adds_unique | 3 |
| 2023-01-02 | 11111111111 | engaged_users | 38 |
| 2023-01-02 | 22222222222 | post_clicks | 22 |
| 2023-01-02 | 22222222222 | adds_unique | 5 |
| 2023-01-02 | 22222222222 | engaged_users | 46 |
| 2023-01-03 | 11111111111 | post_clicks | 59 |
| 2023-01-03 | 11111111111 | adds_unique | 1 |
| 2023-01-03 | 11111111111 | engaged_users | 41 |
| 2023-01-03 | 22222222222 | post_clicks | 74 |
| 2023-01-03 | 22222222222 | adds_unique | 1 |
| 2023-01-03 | 22222222222 | engaged_users | 60 |

I'm able to get the first 3 columns to line up, but not sure how to join the rest of the data.

This is what I got so far....

```
SELECT [date_dimension_header].[date],
       [profile_dimension_header].[profile],
       [metrics_header].[metrics]
FROM
    OPENJSON(@json, '$')
    WITH
    (
        [header_array] NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.header' AS JSON,
        [data_array] NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.data' AS JSON
    ) [api_response]
    CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON([api_response].[header_array], '$[0].rows')
    WITH
    (
        [date] VARCHAR(255) '$'
    ) [date_dimension_header]
    CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON([api_response].[header_array], '$[1].rows')
    WITH
    (
        [profile] VARCHAR(255) '$'
    ) [profile_dimension_header]
    CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON([api_response].[header_array], '$[2].rows')
    WITH
    (
        [metrics] VARCHAR(255) '$'
    ) [metrics_header];
```

Need advice on how to capture the data portion. I tried a couple of joins but either the numbers did not line up to the correct spot or I would see the number of rows go beyond what is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I broke out the header into its own `CTE` so I could reference it repeatedly (you could also consider dropping that into a temp table if the actual file is large and you don't want to read from it multiple times.)

The problem with the way you were doing it is you were using `with` statements to output the data all pretty like; typically a good idea, except in your case, you really need those indices to do your joins. Doing an `openjson` call without using `with` gives you an integer `key` (your index) and a `sql_variant` `value`.

I do a bunch of `openjson` calls on the `data` key, progressively delving deeper and deeper. Then it's just a matter of matching up the correct   `Idx` values from `header` with the `[key]` values of the `openjson` calls.

```
;with header as
(
    select 
        Type = json_value(h.Value, '$.type'),
        Idx = r.[key],
        Value = r.Value
    from openjson(json_query(@JSON, '$.header')) h
    cross apply openjson(h.value) 
    with
    (
        type nvarchar(4000) '$.type',
        rows nvarchar(max) '$.rows' as json
    ) hi
    cross apply openjson(hi.rows) r
)
select 
    Dt = hd.Value,
    Profile = hp.Value,
    Metric = hm.Value,
    MetricValue = dm.Value
from openjson(json_query(@Json, '$.data')) d -- data: date
cross apply openjson(d.Value) dp -- data: profile
cross apply openjson(dp.Value) dm -- data: metric
inner join Header hd -- header: date.day
    on d.[key] = hd.Idx
        and hd.Type = 'date.day'
inner join Header hp -- header: profile
    on dp.[key] = hp.Idx
        and hp.type = 'profile'
inner join header hm -- header: metric
    on dm.[key] = hm.Idx
        and hm.type = 'metric'
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UooUX99K)

Note this does output everything as `nvarchar(max)`. If you need the types well defined, you should probably use `try_convert` on the various columns as you see fit.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect, exactly what I need. I don't think I would have gotten it. I've tested on a few changes on dates, profiles, and metrics and so far so good. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help